# Delete all CSP headers with Chrome Extension to allow iframing

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension

I'm trying to create a Chrome Extension that will inject an iframe sidebar onto any page. I ran into a problem with some sites using CSP directives to restrict what can be framed (example below is LinkedIn). What I thought I would try instead is use [onBeforeSendHeaders](https://developer.chrome.com/extensions/webRequest#implementation) to catch all the `content-security-policy` headers and delete them, but I'm not having any success.

> Refused to frame 'https://example.com/' because it violates the
>   following Content Security Policy directive: "frame-src 'self'
>   *.doubleclick.net www.slideshare.net radar.cedexis.com platform.linkedin.com media-exp1.licdn.com media-exp2.licdn.com
>   m.c.exp1.licdn.com m.c.exp2.licdn.com media-lcdn.licdn.com
>   m.c.lcdn.licdn.com cdn.embedly.com https://www.linkedin.com
>   lichat.azurewebsites.net www.youtube.com www.facebook.com
>   player.vimeo.com embed.ted.com livestream.com embed.gettyimages.com
>   w.soundcloud.com www.lynda.com media.licdn.com".

Here's my manifest file:

```
{
    "manifest_version": 2,
    "name": "My Ext",
    "description": "My ext desc",
    "version": "0.1",
    "content_scripts": [{
        "matches": ["<all_urls>"],
        "js": ["jquery-3.3.1.min.js","content.js","scripts.js"],
        "css": ["content.css"]
    }],
    "background": {
        "scripts": ["background.js"]
    },
    "permissions": ["tabs","activeTab","storage","webRequest","webRequestBlocking","<all_urls>"],
    "browser_action": {
        "default_icon": {
            "16": "images/icon16.png",
            "32": "images/icon32.png",
            "48": "images/icon48.png",
            "128": "images/icon128.png"
        }
    },
    "icons": {
        "16": "images/icon16.png",
        "32": "images/icon32.png",
        "48": "images/icon48.png",
        "128": "images/icon128.png"
    }
}
```

And here's the code in my background.js trying to delete the headers:

```
chrome.webRequest.onBeforeSendHeaders.addListener(
function(details) {
    console.log(details.requestHeaders);
  for (var i = 0; i < details.requestHeaders.length; ++i) {
    if (details.requestHeaders[i].name === 'content-security-policy') {
      details.requestHeaders.splice(i, 1);
      break;
    }
  }
  return {requestHeaders: details.requestHeaders};
},
{urls: ["<all_urls>"]},
["blocking", "requestHeaders"]);
```

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

**EDIT:** I've also tried a method using `onHeadersReceived` to add an additional header allowing example.com. I can see the header is added, and it blocks another frame from being loaded, but example.com is still rejected -- I assume because it still conflicts with the previous header?

The manifest for that version is the same, but here's the background.js for that version:

```
chrome.webRequest.onHeadersReceived.addListener(function(details) {
    console.log(details.responseHeaders);
    details.responseHeaders.push({
        name: 'content-security-policy',
        value: 'frame-src example.com'
    });
    return { responseHeaders: details.responseHeaders };
}, {
    urls: ['*://*.linkedin.com/*']
}, [
    "responseHeaders","blocking"
]);
```

And here's a screenshot of the console log for the content and background:

[image: content console]

[image: background console]

Comment: That's an event for sending headers from the client browser. You need onHeadersReceived.

Comment: I tried that event also (should have mentioned that) and I was able to add my header, but it still errors. I assumed it was because I couldn’t remove/modify the existing header so the two conflicted

Comment: It can only mean some other extension interfered or your code was incorrect. You need to replace the header, not to add it.

Comment: @wOxxOm I edited my post above with the onHeadersReceived attempt I made, so you can see that it added the header correctly, but it still conflicts.

Comment: My point is that you need to find the header in the array, parse it, and add the host name you want into that header's rules.